# HTML ListBox name for data binding in ASP.Net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have **ViewModel** as follows:

```
public class ClientListView
{
    public List<Client> existingClients { get; set; }
    public List<Client> allClients { get; set; }
}
```

Definition of **Client** class as follows:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In the **.cshtml**

```
 <td>
 <select name="existingClients" id="existingClients" multiple size="20">
 @foreach (var item in Model.existingClients)
 {
      <option value=@item.ClientId>@item.Name</option>
 }
 </select>
 </td>
```

Manually I am building the HTMLList element.

In the Controller class the Model binding is not working for the listbox.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientList(ClientListView clientListView)
    {

        return View();

    }
```

It is for sure the names in the html forms and the members names in class(ClientListView) are not matching.

What should be the HTMLList box name in the above case to make sure the Model binding happens and I get the form submitted data in the controller?

I am using the latest ASP.Net MVC.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind a listbox to a collection of complex objects. A `<select multiple>` only posts back a simple array (in you case, an array of the selected `ClientId` values). Your model needs a property (say)

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedClients { get; set; }
```

And rather than manually generating you html, make use of the features of MVC and use the strongly typed html helpers

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedClients, new SelectList(Model.allClients, "ClientId", "Name"))
```

If `SelectedClients` is (say) `[1, 2, 10]`, and `allClients` contains `ClientId` values from 1 to 10, then the 1st, 2nd and last options will be selected when you generate the view.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. You answered my question. I do have two list boxes(selected clients and all clients). One has all the clients and the other has only selected clients. How do model biding can read all the elements of the "selected clients" box.

Comment: What is the point of 2 listboxes? You only need one that displays all clients, and the selected ones are then highlighted in that listbox

Comment: My UI designed with two list boxes. Left side list box(selected clients) has all the selected clients. Right side list box(all clients) has all the clients available in the system. In between two buttons   to add or remove items from the selected clients list box. UI is dictating my steps.

Comment: But what is the point of having 2 (sorry but that makes no sense)?

Comment: It is almost like this in the below link http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Multi-Select-List-Box-fieldChooser/demo/    I have a button in between the two list boxes so the user can move to the selected clients from all clients list box. It is the way the UI is designed.

Comment: That is a really bad design. Not only do you need the javascript for moving items from one to the other you will then have problems posting back because all the items in the 'selected clients' list box must be selected (highlighted) in order to post. Do not do it. Use one list box and let the user highlight which are selected, or better, use a checkbox list (a far better UI) so the user can select them.

Comment: May be bad design from programming point of view. Imagine we have all clients number as 100 and the selected clients is not more than 10 for any time, this is the easy way to notice when user looks at the screen. Otherwise they have to scroll each time to see the selected clients! does it makes sense? I think my only option now is to select all the elements using java script code before submitting the data!

Comment: One suggestion if you still need to use the sample of drag and drop is to bind the selected items with one hidden multi select list which will be posted to server.

Comment: @GaneshaK, Handling the `.submit()` event to ensure all items in the 2nd are selected is one option. Another is just to have a single listbox or checkedlistbox and handle the `click()` event of each option to display a list of all the selected items in a separate div element so the user can see what has been selected without scrolling the listbox